# Running os x app on linux using qemu

Tags: macos, virtualization, qemu

I would like to run a small app (TrunkDecrypt) on my Linux box. Unfortunately the app is compiled for Mac OS X, but I am only running linux. I have read somewhere that qemu supports executing code compiled for different architectures, but it seems qemu only works as a "virtual machine", meaning I have to install a virtual OS first.
My file is of type "Mach-O 64-bit executable", and I want to just "feed" it to qemu and tell it to execute. Is such a thing possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to run an executable you need more than just the CPU it runs on. You also need: 1) a loader, to bring it into memory and perform any page fixups required; 2) the appropriate dynamic libraries, so that it can find the functions it uses; and 3) the appropriate ABI, so that the binding with the dynamic libraries can take place. QEmu does not provide those on its own. But once you have those QEmu will be happy to start the executable up for you.

Comment: what if the app needs no libraries and can execute standalone? would qemu be able to execute the app? If so, do you know how? I have searched the man pages, but it seems the term for this is something I dont recognize...